# missing items in jmeter result tree

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

here is structure of my test.

```
recording controller
    transaction controller
        homepage (transaction controller)
            HTTP Request 1
                Response Assertion (response code = 200)
            HTTP Request 2
                Response Assertion (response code = 200)
            HTTP Request 3
                Response Assertion (response code = 200)
            ....
        login (transaction controller)
            HTTP Request 1
                Response Assertion (response code = 200)
            ....
        logout (transaction controller)
            HTTP Request 1
                Response Assertion (response code = 200)
            ....
    View Results Tree
```

Test is placed inside Ultimate Thread Group (up to 20 threads at once). I placed into each HTTP Request Response Assertion.

When run the the test and after that look in the result tree everything is green, so OK.
But when I clicked through result tree I recognised, that sometimes some items are
missing, but not every time.
see: for example:

```
transaction controller
    homepage
    login
    (logout is missing !!!)
```

Question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ultimate Thread Group you don't have fixed number of loops/iterations, so if you specify some "Hold load for" time span and a thread (virtual user) will be shut down "in the middle" of test execution, i.e. somewhere at `homepage` transaction - it will simply not be able to finish all the remaining requests.

Like

- if you set `Hold Load For` to 1 second - only 1 request will be executed
- if you set `Hold Load For` to 5 seconds - a couple of requests will be executed
- if you set it to 5 minutes - most probably all the requests will be executed at least once, but the number of the requests will mostly depend on your application response time

So if you want the whole sequence to be executed - switch to "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and specify the desired number of iterations

Also using JMeter GUI mode and View Results Tree listener for executing load tests is not the best idea, you [should be running your JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) and use [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) for results analysis.